# can anybody help me to correct this "argv" program?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import sys
import re

x = sys.argv[1]
y = sys.argv[2]

f = open("formula.txt" ,'r')
line = f.read()
match = re.search(r'x',line,re.M|re.I)

match = re.search(r'y',line,re.M|re.I)

f.close()
print x
print y
```

I tried this above program but I could not get the output?

~

## ~

Desire output should follows:

when I  want execute the above program;

```
>>>python argument.py circle_area rectangle_area
```

the output should like this:

```
x = 2*3.14*r*r
y = l*b
```

---

And the given file in program  is formula.txt

formula.txt file contains following data;

```
circle_area = '3.14*r*r'

circle_circumference = '2*3.14*r'

rectangle_area = 'l*b'

rectangle_perimeter = '2(l+b)'
------------------------------------
~
```

can anybody help me to implement above.

Comment: What is the stacktrace?

Comment: I am beginner of python...

Comment: when ever pass two argv1 and argv2

Comment: output would be `3.14*r*r` and `l*b`, since we are passing circle_area and rectangle_area

Comment: like example of executing command; python test.py  argv1  argv2                                 those argvs as to search  in file i.e.,formula.txt . ofter searching that formula it as to print on screen.

Comment: How does it not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made so many mistakes in your code.

- Don't put  variable names inside quotes.
- Use capturing groups or lookarounds to match the text you want to print.
- Use `.group()` attribute in `re.search` function to get the matched text.

Code  should look like.

```
import sys
import re

x = sys.argv[1]
y = sys.argv[2]

f = open("formula.txt" ,'r')
line = f.read()
match1 = re.search(x + r"\s*=\s*'([^']*)'" , line, re.M|re.I).group(1)
match2 = re.search(y + r"\s*=\s*'([^']*)'" , line, re.M|re.I).group(1)
f.close()
print match1
print match2
```

`r"\s*=\s*'([^']*)'"`, `\s*` matches zero or more spaces and `[^']*` matches any character but not of a single quote, zero or more times. This text (*value part*) was captured into group 1 . Later we refer the captured chars by specifying the index number in group attribute.

Comment: could you explain this regex logic  which  i am not understood?                                                               match1 = re.search(x + r"\s*=\s*'([^']*)'" , line, re.M|re.I).group(1)
    match2 = re.search(y + r"\s*=\s*'([^']*)'" , line, re.M|re.I).group(1)                                          Do n't mind i am new to python.

Comment: And what is use of    =\s*

Comment: `=` matches a literal `=` sign, so `=\s*` matches an `=` sign along with the following spaces.

Answer (score 0):

First off you don't search argument values, rather do:

```
match = re.search(r"^%s\s+=\s*'(.*)'" % x, line, re.M|re.I)
```

Then do something with the match like putting it back into existing variable.

```
x = match.group(1)
```

Comment: could you explian how this regex works......    re.search(r"^%s\s+=\s+'(.*)'" % x, line, re.I)

Comment: ^ for start of line, %s is the variable name you are retrieving, \s+ one or more spaces, '(.*)' grabs your calculation.

Comment: upto    r"^%s\s+     i got it. ofter this   =\s+ meaning is?

Comment: that there is another on or more spaces after =

Comment: import sys
import re

x = sys.argv[1]

f = open("formula.txt" ,'r')
line = f.read()
match = re.search(r"^%s\s+'(.*)'" % x, line, re.M|re.I)
f.close()
x = match.group(1)
print x
----------->when i am executing above code i am geting error.                                                                                                                     The Error is as follows: $ python argvone.py circle_area          Traceback (most recent call last): File "argvone.py", line 10, in x = match.group(1) AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'